# INSTAPRESS WP PLUGIN - CSS Image Sizing on Mobile and Desktop alignment

Tags: css, layout, mobile, wordpress-theming, responsive-design

I am having issues getting my Instagram images to display properly. I have tried all types of tricks and changes but cannot get it to look consistent on both desktop and mobile. It looks perfect when at full window size and across all browsers (except mobile), but when I change the size of the browser viewing window it gets all weird.

Here is my issue:

1. I need all the horizontal Instagram images to be responsive, meaning when I do change the size of the browser window they will adjust to the dimensions that are appropriate to view them properly. I want them to always stay in a row of 5 images across...

Here is a link to the work in progress:

http://www.jaygiroux.com/wordpress/

I have tried modifying the instapress.css to the best of my abilities but now I'm just stuck. I tried using percentages instead of pixels in some places but it's still not working...

Comment: You shouldn' modify the `foundation.css`, overload the styles in another file. Think what is going to happen is you update your foundation.css ;)

Comment: I have been using the style.css for most changes, besides the simple stuff...

Answer (score 1):

What im reading online is that until version 3 nivo slider is not responsive, so you might want to update the library.

http://nivo.dev7studios.com/2012/05/30/the-nivo-slider-is-responsive/

Also i noticed that you're calling the  tag twice (the first one is between the ie class compatibility code) so watch out for that too.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I have since replaced the Nivo Slider with a Responsive Slider...